# Can I mount a GCS bucket inside Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I know that Kubernetes does not support mounting GCS buckets inside a Pod. But If I use GoogleFuse to mount a GCS bucket on the Node and then expose it to a Pod as a host path will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. For Host Path volumes, kube doesn't enforce any policy. But if your FUSE daemon restarts, the mount will become inaccessible. AFAIK, kube does not support mount propagation for volumes.

Comment: are there any plans to support mount propagation in Kube? Docker seem to support it now: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17034